# Conjugation in a group seen as change of variable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

From Complex Made Simple:

> If $G$ is a group and $a, b \in G$, then $b$ is said to be conjugate to $a$ if $b = c^{-1}ac$ for some $c \in G$. Note that if G is a group of mappings from a set X to itself (with composition as the group operation) then this is the same as saying that $b$ is equivalent to $a$ after a "change of variables" given by c.

My question is: why is this figured out like a change of variable. I don't understand this association. What is intuition behind this? Thanks!

Comment: Just replace $a$ by $c^{-1}ac$. So change the "variables", from $a$ to $a^c=c^{-1}ac$. Think of invertible matrices and the Jordan form. For given $A\in GL_n(K)$ consider $S^{-1}AS$, so that this matrix has Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G$ acts on a set $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$. Say $c$ corresponds to the permutation that shifts every index by $1$, so $cx_i = x_{i+1}$ if $1\leq i\lt n$, and $cx_n=x_1$.

Now, consider $a$ act by exchanging $x_2$ and $x_3$, and let $b$ act by exchanging $x_1$ and $x_2$.

What does $cbc^{-1}$ do? It does what $a$ does: $x_2$ is mapped to $x_1$ by $c^{-1}$, then $b$ exchanges it with $x_2$, and then $c$ sends it to $x_3$; and it fixes everything else.

Now, say we use $c$ as a "relabeling" map: we define new variables $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ by $y_i = cx_i$.

Then $b$ exchanges $x_1$ and $x_2$, and $a=cbc^{-1}$ exchanges $y_1$ and $y_2$. More generally, if you take any element $g\in G$, then $cgc^{-1}$ does to $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ exactly what $g$ does to $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, in the sense that if $gx_i = x_j$, then $(cgc^{-1})y_i = y_j$.

Viewed that way, you can think of $c$ as performing a kind of "change of variables" on the $x_i$, turning them in to the $y_i$, so that $cgc^{-1}$ acts on the $y$s the same way that $g$ acts on $x$s.

For elements of $S_n$, this is reflected in the fact that, for example,
$$\sigma(a_1\cdots a_k)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a_1)\cdots \sigma(a_n)).$$

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question. There are trying to make a definition (as to when two group elements are conjugate): and, in the context of group theory - the words `change of variable' doesn't make much sense. If you know about $S_4$, the symmetric group with $24$ elements, then all $2$ cycles (that is $(12),(13),(14),(23),(24),(34)$) are conjugate to each other. And, all $3$ cycles (that is $(123),(132),(124),(142),(134),(143),(234)$ and $(243)$) are conjugate to each other. Similarly all the $4$ cycles $(1234),(1243),(1324),(1342),(1423)$ and $(1432)$ are all conjugate to each other. Can you try to find a $g$ (in $S_4$) such that $(12)=g^{-1}(14)g$?

You may like to prove a $2$-cycle is not conjugate to a $3$-cycle (that is, there is no element $g$ in $S_4$ such that $g^{-1}(12)g=(234)$), for example. Also, my comments after the words "if you know about $S_4$" can be generalized to groups like $S_n$ in general. A standard algebra book can explain this more, if you are wondering (or looking for) examples of 'conjugate' group elements.

Regarding intuition, if one would like to construct a bijective homomorphism from a group to itself: say (if $G=S_3$) a map from $G$ to $G$, then we can fix the element $g=(123) \in S_3$, and let $\phi_g: G \to G$ be $\phi(h)=(123)^{-1}h(123)$. Thanks.